Does a charged quantum harmonic oscillator in ground state perturb EM field?
Assume we have a quantum harmonic oscillator in its ground state.
If we attach a charge to the oscillator will it produce an oscillating electromagnetic field?

As in, perturb the EM field from the ground $\mathrm{d}A=0$ state? If so the answer seems trivially yes, doesn’t it?

I mean, the charge makes its own electric field. It's unclear to me what your question really is here.  Can you clarify?

March - True. I was wondering if the charged quantum oscillator produces an oscillating EM field even when it’s in the ground state.

The charge distribution is not oscillating in the ground state

@Andrew My comment was wrong and I’ve deleted it.

I explored two different approach, semiclassical and quantum.
Semiclassical approach
We can consider the electric field radiated by an accelerated charge (as in The Feynman lectures Vol. I chapter 28.2)
$$
\vec E(\vec x',t) = {-q\over 4\pi \epsilon_0 c^2} {d^2\over dt^2}\left( {\langle\vec x\rangle(t_r)-\vec x' \over|\langle \vec x\rangle(t_r)-\vec x'|}\right)
$$
where $t_r$ is the retarded time, $\langle \vec x\rangle(t)$ is the mean position of the particle and we are considering the field at point $\vec x'$. We could use this expression to calculate the electric field radiated by, for example, an harmonic oscillator in coherent state, for which we have
$$
\langle \vec x\rangle (t) = \sqrt{\frac{2\hbar}{m\omega}}\Re[\alpha(t)]= |\alpha(0)|  \sqrt{\frac{2\hbar}{m\omega}} \cos (\sigma - \omega t)
$$
The ground is state is a coherent state with $\alpha = 0$, so the mean position is zero all the time and $\vec E = 0$.
Full Quantum Approach
But you could be skeptical since I considered a classical EM (I am). Let's consider a quantum EM then. The full Hamiltonian is
$$
H = H_{HO} + H_{EM} + H_I
$$
where $H_I$ is the interaction Hamiltonian between the quantum harmonic oscillator and the EM field. Ignoring quadratic terms, this interaction usually is written as
$$
H_I = {q\over mc} pA
$$
where $p$ is the momentum of the oscillator along the direction of polarization of the field. The state
$$|0\rangle_{OH}|0\rangle_{EM}$$
Is not an eigenstate of the interaction term, so the system will not remain in this state.
EDIT 2::
As @Andrew pointed out in the comment section, my previous approach was not conserving energy. The correct approach is to consider the interaction as a time-dependent perturbation an write
$$
H_I = {q\over mc}\sqrt{\hbar \over 2m\omega} \sum_k \left ( a a_{\vec k}e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r}e^{-i(\omega +\omega_{\vec k})} - \frac{i}{m\omega} a^\dagger a_{\vec k}e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r}e^{i(\omega -\omega_{\vec k})} - a a_{\vec k}^\dagger e^{-i\vec k \cdot \vec r}e^{-i(\omega -\omega_{\vec k})} + \frac{i}{m\omega} a^\dagger a^\dagger_{\vec k}e^{-i\vec k \cdot \vec r}e^{i(\omega +\omega_{\vec k})} \right)
$$
All terms but last one vanish for the state aforementioned. The last term is anti-ressonant, and by Rotating wave approximation, this effect would vanish for long range time intervals. So in the end, the field could suffer a transition for an excited state, but it will be just a negligible fluctuation.

Wouldn't a process where you start with zero particles and end up with one photon and one quantum of the charged harmonic oscillator violate energy conservation?

You're right, but the excited state is not stationary either, so I think it will not remain so by long time. I think this transition could be thought as a small fluctuation and the conservation of energy is respected for times longer than the time-energy uncertainty relation

This still doesn't seem right to me. One potential issue is that your interaction Hamiltonian is quadratic, so you might be effectively seeing an effect like neutrino oscillations where you get transitions essentially because of your choice of basis, but you could choose a basis where these transitions go away. It is true that quantum fluctuations will renormalize the vacuum state, but you should find the amplitude between the vacuum and any excited state is zero, unless you input an external source.

I made this calculation based on atom-field interaction like the Jaynes-Cummings model. There, these interaction term like $a^\dagger a_{\ket k}^\dagger$ are discarded with the rotating wave approximation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaynes%E2%80%93Cummings_model#Rotating_frame_and_rotating-wave_approximation in fact, I didn't considered the temporal oscillations, which could solve this issue

Got it! I come from more of a particle physics/cosmology than optics background, and I've noticed sometimes the two communities think about things a little differently (even though it's all the same in the end). Thanks for clarifying!
